# Nuxt.js Caching Problem and 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' Problem

Tags: axios, http-headers, nuxt.js, web-deployment

I've just deployed a nuxt app to the server, but it caches in a bad way. in any device, logged in or not, I get  one user information, it's cookie and token! I tried to find out what is the problem, I searched and now I think because `cache-control: public` with `max-age=31536000`, now I've tried to set it to `private` or `no-cache`.

I have two questions:

1. which `cache-control` value should I use?  `private` or `no-cache`, etc? or even is this problem is because of caching?
2. when I try to set headers of axios in `nuxt.config.js` , I get this error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url of the backend' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field cache-control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

I've tried to set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` but it did'n work, my `nuxt.config.js`, the axios part is like this:

```
axios: {
        baseURL: 'backend',
        headers: {
            common: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'cache-control',
                'cache-control': 'private',
            },
        },
    }
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After a While, I found the answer, Nuxt.js by default cache all the **responses** (it does not any relation to axios requests) in it's node server, so if you want to fix this situation add `cache: false` to `build` property in `nuxt.config.js` for universal mode (for static mode add this property to `generate`)

```
// nuxt.config.js

{
// ...

  build: {
      cache: false
  }

// ...
}
```

[More info in the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#cache)

Comment: The cache flag only cache the webpack build and does no mean http cache. I think your issue might be related to how you init your data or store. They must be functions instead of object, otherwise data would be shared across request.